# Where do SonOff schedules reside?

Tags: smart-home, sonoff

Using the stock firmware, I've set up a schedule for my one SonOff RF using the app on my phone. Observation suggests that this schedule is not running, and I wonder if this is because my phone is aggressive about killing background processes when in screen-off state.

There are at least 3 possible locations for the schedule function, (phone / cloud / endpoint), and I'd assumed that based on the app's behaviour, this was likely to be actually managed in the endpoint so it wouldn't be relying on either internet connectivity or CPU resource on my phone. Is there a definitive answer, and will the 3rd party firmware for these switches give more reliable performance?

Comment: Given that the SonOff is just a ESP8266 under the covers I'm tempted to say it's not on the endpoint as it doesn't have a RTC iirc

Comment: But it's an always on, internet connected device. Your deduction is supported by my observation though.

Answer (score 1):

On the endpoint. They get their time from the net and timers continue to work without the net. Even after reflashing the firmware (for example with Tasmota) the endpoint retains the ability to store timers and obtain the time from the net.

Comment: Of course (as indicated by hardillb), the Sonoff is just a ESP8266, so it doesn't have a Real Time Clock (RTC). I imagine its time would drift quiet radically if not connected to the net.